Transparent Glass Material Eevee Blender version 4.2
I encounter difficulties in creating glass material in Blender version 4.2.
Same scene in Blender 4.1 work fine, but in version 4.2 the glass material is not still transparent...
I have attached here the file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wDNRYiUxGS5DmnwyHT5I1_hUg1zbKr6M/view?usp=sharing
Please check in blender version 4.2


i can confirm that the same "effect" happens on Blender 4.3...

@Chris Oh, you guys... always using the latest releases without knowing how they work... you should watch some tutorials on what's new in new versions ;)

@GordonBrinkmann: don't be jealous! it's because we can ...but we don't know what we are doing! :D

In the Settings of the material, for transmissive materials like glass you now have to use the Render Method > Dithered and you have to enable Raytraced Transmission.

And to use Raytraced Transmission, of course _Raytracing has to be enabled in the Render Properties and the Method has to be Screen-Trace ( which you already had in your file).


i am thinking about flagging the answer as off-topic....but because i have a good day...+1 ;)

@Chris Thanks!  :D  It is actually just a coincidence that I watched a video about the changes a few days ago and saw this...
